# GETTING ERROR IN SOCKETFIRST PROGRAM

Tags: sockets

I don't know why I am getting the error I don't know what does connection reset by peers mean please explain. I am stuck on this. I only recently started with network programming...

```
package socket1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

///**
// *
// * @author Cool
// */
public class Socket1 {

    /**
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
            Socket s=new Socket("whois.internic.net",43);
            if(s.isConnected())
            {
                System.out.println("Succesfully connected");
                Scanner st=new Scanner(System.in);
                String url;
                url = "google.com";
                System.out.println(url);
                InputStream in=s.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream();
                byte buf[]=url.getBytes();
                out.write(buf);
                int c;
                while((c= in.read())!=-1)
                {
                    System.out.print((char)c);
                }
               s.close();
            }else
            {
                System.out.println("Not connected right now ");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Socket1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the error which I get:

> run:
>   Succesfully connected
>   google.com
>   socket1.Socket1 main
>   SEVERE: null
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
>         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
>         at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:223)
>         at socket1.Socket1.main(Socket1.java:46)
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: Answering your question " I don't know what does connection reset by peers mean": Have you even tried searching for it? It's extensively detailed in the documentation and in plenty of questions here in SO.

Comment: Try adding a newline to your query string: i.e. `url = "google.com\n";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a new line to your query string solves the issue as follows `query = "google.com\n";`